# what is the probality of taking first blue and last red ball when picking 6 balls?

Tags: probability

There is 36 ballls.

12 are red R
12 are blue B
12 are yellow

What is the probability of taking first blue and last red ball when picking 6 balls? (Not returning them back).

Lets say A is any ball.

So the order would look like this:

BAAAAR

I so far I came to this:

$$\frac
{12 * 35 * 34 * 33 * 32 *  X}
{36 * 35 * 34 * 33 * 32 * 31}
$$

now I am stuck of what to put instead of X? I dont know what is the probability of taking the last red ball.

Because it differs, depending on previuous 4 balls. How many are left? It can be 12 or 11 or 10 or 9 or 8 red balls left.

---

### Edited:

Thanks for quick answers.

After writing post I thinked this could be correct way, which I calculated already:

Divide in the parts:

**There is 0 red balls in the middle**

$$\frac
{12 * 23 * 22 * 21 * 20 * 12}
{36 * 35 * 34 * 33 * 32 * 31}
$$

**There is 1 red ball in the middle, lets say 2nd one:**

$$\frac
{12 * 12 * 23 * 22 * 21 * 11}
{36 * 35 * 34 * 33 * 32 * 31}
$$

But in the middle there is 4 ways to put red ball, so multiply by 4.

**There are 2 red balls in the middle:**
$$\frac
{12 * 12 * 11 * 23 * 22 * 10}
{36 * 35 * 34 * 33 * 32 * 31}
$$
And 6 ways to put in the middle  4! / (2! * 2!) so multiply by 6

**There are 3 red balls in the middle:**
$$\frac
{12 * 12 * 11 * 10 * 23 * 9}
{36 * 35 * 34 * 33 * 32 * 31}
$$
and 4 ways to put them

**There are 4 balls in the middle:**
$$\frac
{12 * 12 * 11 * 10 * 9 * 8}
{36 * 35 * 34 * 33 * 32 * 31}
$$
And add all of them aproximatelly:
$$
0.02182163187 + 0.04800759013 + 0.0342911358 + 0.00935212794 + 0.00081322851 = \fbox{0.11428571425}
$$
So what do you think is this good way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of the balls as having distinct ID numbers. All sequences of $6$ balls (thinking of ID numbers, not colours) are equally likely.

The probability the first is blue is $\frac{12}{36}$. The probability the sixth is red, **given** the first was blue, is $\frac{12}{35}$. Multiply.

Comment: hmm, yea simple calculation is getting same answer :) but still I dont understand - you say given the first was blue. But we dont know what are given balls in the middle. Hmm, maybe thats the reason that we dont know. So its kind of same as if 1st ball is blue and 2nd ball is red.

Comment: Yes, all sequences are equally likely, so if first, second makes the intuition clearer, do it. The probability the second is red is the same as the probability the $17$-th is red.

Comment: (1) If the position doesn't matter, then why the probability of the sixth is red is not equal to $\frac{12}{36}$? (2) If **given the first was blue**  matters, why aren't we considering the middle balls so that the probability of the sixth is red is equal to $\frac{12}{31}$? (3) doesn't The situation become complex if the middle ball(s) is/are red?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: There are $\binom{36}66!$ sequences of $6$ balls that you could choose without replacement, so that will be the denominator of the desired probability; you already found that. Now we need to count the sequences that start with a blue ball and end with a red ball. The trick is **not** to do the calculation in the order in which the balls are picked.

There are $12$ ways to pick the blue ball at the beginning and $12$ ways to pick the red ball at the end. That leaves $34$ balls; how many different sequences of $4$ balls can you pick from those $34$? If that number is $n$, there are $12^2n=144n$ sequences that start with a blue ball and end with a red ball.

Answer (score 0):

Probability of taking first ball blue is $\frac13$, now you peek $4$ balls out of $35$ (any combination) and you have to calculate probability to peek the sixth ball red.

The order of the 4 intermediate balls are not important, only how many red balls are there, which is a number between $0$ and $4$.

Probability of taking $0$ red balls from a set of $12$ red balls and $23$ non-red balls is $p_0=\frac{23}{35}\cdot\frac{22}{34}\cdot\frac{21}{33}\cdot\frac{20}{32}=\frac{23}{136}$.

Probability for taking exactly $1$ red is $p_1=\frac{23}{35}\cdot\frac{22}{34}\cdot\frac{21}{33}\cdot\frac{12}{32}=\frac{69}{680}$.

We can calculate similarly $p_2, p_3, p_4$ to be $p_2=\frac{253}{4760}$, $p_3=\frac{23}{952}$ and $p_4=\frac9{952}$.

Now, let's $q_n$ be the probability of taking last ball red, given that you have already pick $n$ red balls, then $q_n=\frac{12-n}{31}$.

Now, the probability you are asking is
$$P=\sum_{n=0}^4\frac13\cdot p_nq_n.$$

Another way to write this, and written $\frac13$ as $\frac{12}{36}$ is:
$$P=\frac{12\cdot23\cdot22\cdot21\cdot20\cdot12}{36\cdot35\cdot34\cdot33\cdot32\cdot31}+\frac{12\cdot23\cdot22\cdot21\cdot12\cdot11}{36\cdot35\cdot34\cdot33\cdot32\cdot31}+\frac{12\cdot23\cdot22\cdot12\cdot11\cdot10}{36\cdot35\cdot34\cdot33\cdot32\cdot31}+\frac{12\cdot23\cdot12\cdot11\cdot10\cdot9}{36\cdot35\cdot34\cdot33\cdot32\cdot31}+\frac{12\cdot12\cdot11\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8}{36\cdot35\cdot34\cdot33\cdot32\cdot31}$$

---

### Update:

The probability $p_n$ should be multiplied by the ways position-wise in which you can put $n$ red balls in those four intermediate balls.  This gives:
$$P=\sum_{n=0}^4\frac13\cdot \binom4np_nq_n.$$ where $\binom4n=\frac{4!}{n!(4-n)!}$.

Comment: why are you not multiplying by amount of ways? lets say in the q1 - red ball can be in any of the places. I think you calculated of red being in that specific place.

Comment: @SPeed_FANat1c, I probably missed that factor.  Uppon inspection I think André is right (and probably putting my missing factors will get that answer)

Comment: And, effectively, adding this factor the answer is numerically equivalent to the one from André Nikolas, which means I overcalculated.