# The probality of taking first blue and last red ball when picking 6 balls

Tags: probability

[In the post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526805/what-is-the-probality-of-taking-first-blue-and-last-red-ball-when-picking-6-ball) the question was:

There is $36$ balls. $12$ are red R, $12$ are blue B, $12$ are yellow.

What is the probability of taking first blue and last red ball when picking $6$ balls? (Not returning them back).

There is a quick answer from [André Nicolas](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526805/what-is-the-probality-of-taking-first-blue-and-last-red-ball-when-picking-6-ball/526814#526814).

> Think of the balls as having distinct ID numbers. All sequences of $6$ balls (thinking of ID numbers, not colours) are equally likely.
>
> The probability the first is blue is $\frac{12}{36}$. The probability the sixth is red, **given** the first was blue, is $\frac{12}{35}$. Multiply.

But I can't still visualize.

(1) If the position doesn't matter, then why the probability of the last ball is red is not equal to $\frac{12}{36}$?

(2) If **given the first was blue** matters, then why aren't we considering the middle balls so that the probability of the last ball is red is equal to $\frac{12}{31}$?

(3) doesn't The situation become complex if the middle ball(s) is/are red?

Comment: Simplify the situation to three balls. It may help you see why. Or, if you think of the "last ball" as being "the second ball", you can see why the rest of them don't matter. Certainly swapping them around doesnt change the probability, it just exchanges their numerators, and multiplication is commutative.

Comment: It would be no different if you closed your eyes, reached in and grabbed six balls at once, then threw four back in the pot and looked at the two remaining balls one at a time. And that would be no different than drawing one ball without replacement then drawing a second ball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) The probability the last ball is red **is** 12/36. Like the answerer emphasized, the probability the last ball is red **given** the first is blue is 12/35. The denominator is 35 cause there's only 35 balls left after picking the first one and the numerator is 12 since there's 12 red balls left (since the first ball chosen was not red).

(2) Why would we consider the middle balls? We have no information about them and thus do not need to condition on them at all.

(3) No. Of course if we learned of the information of what the middle balls were, it would affect the conditional probability of the last one being red, but we don't. We are "averaging over" the middle balls.

In order to draw the first ball blue and the last ball red, what needs to happen is:

a. The first ball we pick is blue (prob $\frac{12}{36}$)

b. and then, after picking the first ball blue, the last one needs to be red. You can think of this as a new experiment where theres 11 blue, 12 yellow and 12 red... what's the probability the last ball is red then? It's 12/35.

The desired outcome occurs iff both these things happen. Thus the probability is (12/36)*(12/35)

Comment: Could you please explain what did you mean by `We are "averaging over" the middle balls.`?

Comment: I just meant they can have any configuration consistent with the fact that the first is blue and the last is red and we take all those possibilities into account. An equally good way to do the calculation is to take (# of configurations where the first is blue and the last is red) / (total # possible configurations). The numerator is 12*12*34! for 12 choices for the first blue ball * 12 choices for the last red ball * 34! configurations for the other 34 balls. The denominator is 36! for all the possible rearrangements of the balls. So you get 12*12*34!/36! = 12*12/35/36.

Comment: does the number of favorable outcomes $=12×12×34!$
imply the first blue and the last red when we pick n (where $n=3,4,…,36$) balls without replacement? But if we were to pick only two balls without replacement where the first is blue and second red, then isn't the number of favorable outcome $=12×12$?

Comment: if balls don't have any preference for position then why $34!=34P_{34}$? By $34!$, I understand that the number of ways to arrange $34$ objects taken $34$ at a time. does the number of favorable outcomes $=12×12×34!$ imply the first blue and the last red when we pick $36$ balls out of $36$ balls without replacement?

Comment: We're just counting the # of configurations. I think another commenter suggested imagining the balls labeled 1-36 Then imagine the first 1-12 are blue, etc. Now we just count the number of ways to arrange them in a row that have leftmost blue and rightmost red, i.e. the number of favorable outcomes. Pick one of the 12 blues and 1 of the 12 reds and put them in front and back then arrange the other 34 any way and you have a favorable outcome. If it's not clear why the total number is 12 * 12 *34!, maybe try it for smaller numbers where you can actually enumerate them.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of choosing balls randomly, imagine them laid out randomly in a row,
and choose #$1$ and #$6$. [It's the same thing ]

P(first ball is blue) $= \frac{12}{36}$

Now look at the situation where $35$ balls **including $12$ red** are left at serials $2-36$

Since **balls don't have any preference for positions**, a red ball **now** has a $Pr =\frac{12}{35}$ of occupying **any** of these positions, hence a $Pr=\frac{12}{35}$ of being at #6,
i.e. P(sixth red | first blue ) $=\frac{12}{35}$

You should be able now to see that P(first blue $\cap$ sixth red ) $= \frac{12}{36}\frac{12}{35}$

Furthermore, P( first yellow $\cap$ sixth red) $= \frac{12}{36}\frac{12}{35}$,
and P(first red $\cap$ sixth red) $= \frac{12}{36}\frac{11}{35}$